# Symfony eventsubscriber on a specific path

Tags: php, symfony, event-handling

So in our Symfony application, we have several EventSubscribers. Some of them should only be triggered on our main website, some only on our admin section (all routes with /admin).

Now, most of the EventSubscribers are using KernelEvents::CONTROLLER, like this:

```php
public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array {
    return [
        KernelEvents::REQUEST => 'onRequestEvent'
    ];
}
```

This however makes it so even on our non-/admin routes, this gets called. We do have a check in our `onRequestEvent` function that returns if the requestUri doesn't contain /admin, but I find this a pretty bad way of doing it, since the services in the controller still gets injected.

```php
public function onRequestEvent(RequestEvent $event) {
    if (strpos($event->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), '/admin') === false) {
        return;
    }

    // .. CODE HERE
}
```

My question is, is there a way to make EventSubscribers work on specific routes (or paths)? Or should I just keep it like this? Or is there a better way of doing it?

I was thinking these are my options:

- Keep it like this (and possibly make it so the services in the constructor gets injected a different way)
- Make a custom AbstractController which dispatches a custom Event to handle logic in that
- Dispatch a custom Event in every controller function (I would say this isn't the best but maybe it is)

What is the best way of doing the EventSubscribers the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom event, let's say "FrontRequestEvent" and use a light subscriber to the Symfony RequestEvent to trigger it after you check the path.

```
public function onRequestEvent(RequestEvent $event) {
    if (strpos($event->getRequest()->getRequestUri(), '/admin') === false) {
        return;
    }

    // .. DISPATCH FrontRequestEvent EVENT HERE
}
```

Then, you can create a subscriber to your event, where you can inject all your dependencies. This way, you instantiate dependencies only when needed.

Comment: That's something I haven't thought of, though it does add more events and for example onRequestEvent is still called every time. I assume it doesn't affect performance that much?

Comment: In the listener to the framework Request event, you would just have the string comparison to figure out if you need to dispatch your custom FrontRequest event. I would say this qualifies as "no performance impact". I don't think there is a way to do this without adding the custom event or injecting your dependencies in the sf Request event listener, which could affect performance.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll go with this approach then